# Using trongrid api key, not affecting to dashboard query count

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptocurrency, tron, tronweb

im using this method but meet with  503 statusCode
and also can not see any query from my app ((

```
const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.trongrid.io/',
    headers: { "TRON-PRO-API-KEY": 'your api key' },
    privateKey: 'your private key'
})
```

Upd. Funally figure out how to solve.
Udpate my tronWeb to 3.2.6 version

Answer (score 0):

First you shuld initialize tronweb
for example index.js

```
const TronWeb = require("tronweb");

const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.trongrid.io/',
    headers: { "TRON-PRO-API-KEY": 'Here is api key' },
    privateKey: 'here is pk'
});
```

Then you should use contract methods:

```
async function f() {
    let instance = await tronWeb.contract.at('here is contract address');
    let result = await instance.f().call();
    console.log(result);
}
f();
```

Where method instance.f() - your method of smart contract example `getName()`
use command `node index.js`